# Exercise - analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume that $f$ is an analytic function on $|z|<2$

$f(0)=f'(0)=0$ , $f''(0) \not= 0$, $f(1/3)=i/12$ , $|f(z)|\le3$ for $|z|<2$

then find the value of $f(2i/3)$.

Thank you

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Nothing... Sorry I really don't know

Comment: I wonder whether this problem can be done with only that data...nothing else is given about the function? Even representing it as a power series around zero, say, doesn't seem to lead to something definite. Interesting question. +1

Comment: Oh sorry I omitted something. f is bounded

Comment: I don't get it: any analytic function is bounded on any compact subset of $\;\Bbb C\;$ , so your is so for example in $\;|z|\le 2\;$ . Is this what you meant?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18991/discussion-between-user128766-and-timbuc).

Comment: @Timbuc Did you see the edit of the question? The function is not only bounded, it's $|f(z)| \le 3$ on the disc at hand.

Comment: Hint: $g(z) = \frac{1}{3}f(2z)$. Schwarz.

Comment: @DanielFischer What is the Schwarz?

Comment: @user128766: Schwarz's Lemma. Google it. This solves your problem.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: @user128766: Is the answer : $ 4/3 $ ?

Comment: @SrinivasK My answer is 1/3

Answer (score 0):

Proceed as in Schwarz Lemma to conclude that $f(z)=\frac{3i}{4}z^2$.